# Python easy catch all Traceback (most recent call last) in wx python app

Tags: python, exception

I have written a python application using wx python which is quite a complex script, classes, etc. The application takes xml files from external sources and manipulates them, this sometimes causes unexpected exceptions in various different areas of the script. This is fine when running the application in IDLE, I am able to see any exceptions in the IDLE shell, but I need to run this as a stand alone application, I use py2app and pyinstaller. So cutting to the chase, my question is... When running as standalone application I would like to print any python exceptions out to a wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl window, or something like that, so I can at least see any odd things occurring. I have looked at catching exceptions with `try` and `except Exception` but I would have to virtually re-write my application to include these types of exceptions. What are my options?
Here is a very small example of my application, obviously with the guts missing:

```
import wx
import os
import os.path
import subprocess
import pipes
import platform
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys
import threading
import wx.stc as stc
import traceback

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(600, 550), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | 
                                                wx.RESIZE_BOX | 
                                                wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))

        self.run_params = {}
        self.run_params["refresh"] = False
        systemType = platform.system()
.........................

app = wx.App()
MainWindow(None, -1, 'My Application')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define an "unhandled exception handler" that will get called with any exception anywhere in the code that happens outside of a `try` block?

Comment: Yes, that sounds exactly what I want as long as I can use only 1 try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google for the "wxpython traceback" turned up the article [CustomExceptionHandling](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CustomExceptionHandling) at the wxpython wiki.

The wiki page has code samples for doing a whole lot more than you're asking for, like submitting bug reports by email. I'll just show how to do the simplest thing that fits the question, but please read the page for more ideas.

```
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        sys.excepthook = self.OnException
        # your existing OnInit code

    def OnException(self, type, value, tb):
        lines = traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb)
        msg = '\n'.join(lines)
        # Now create your dialog and display msg
```

Note that if your app wasn't written with exception safety in mind, there's a pretty good chance that an unhandled exception means you're in an likely unrecoverable state, and there's no easy way to tell whether you are or not. So, your dialog should probably just have an "Exit" button, and you should display it modally and then exit hard once it's clicked.

---

If you have a multithreaded application, this may not work because `threading` has its own exception handler on each thread. See [#1230540](http://bugs.python.org/issue1230540) for various solutions for this problem. But a few caveats:

- You will either need to make the main thread call `sys.excepthook` for you, instead of calling it directly on the worker thread, or write your `excepthook` to be worker-thread-safe (in particular, to make it ask the main thread to create the dialog on its behalf). I'll show how to do that below, although it's untested code and I haven't used wx in a while so it'll probably need a bit of work.
- If you're using `Thread` subclasses, instead of using the class as-is with `target` functions, only [Ian Beaver's solution](http://bugs.python.org/msg91244) will work for you; I'm not going to show that, but it's not too tricky.
- If your GUI's main loop is not running on the main thread (which is uncommon, but not impossible, or illegal), this may not work without some big changes; I don't remember how to deal with those.
- There are bugs in earlier versions of Python that make some of these solutions not work; I don't know which versions or what they are.

So, here's my untested wx-tailored version of a simplified version of [Jonathan Ellis's solution](http://bugs.python.org/msg25696):

```
import sys
import threading
import wx

ID_EXCEPTHOOK = wx.NewId()

def EVT_EXCEPTHOOK(win, func):
    win.Connect(-1, -1, ID_EXCEPTHOOK, func)

class ExceptionEvent(wx.PyEvent):
    def __init__(self, type, value, tb):
        super(ExceptionEvent, self).__init__()
        self.SetEventType(ID_EXCEPTHOOK)
        self.type, self.value, self.tb = type, value, tb

class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, main_window, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.main_window = main_window
    def run(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super(WorkerThread, self).run(*args, **kwargs)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            wx.PostEvent(self.main_window, ExceptionEvent(*sys.exc_info()))

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        # existing code
        EVT_EXCEPTHOOK(self, self.OnException)
    def OnException(self, event):
        sys.excepthook(event.type, event.value, event.tb)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    # same as before
```

Now, whenever you create a thread, you have to use `WorkerThread` instead of `Thread`, and pass it your `MainFrame` instance as an extra first argument. But presumably you create threads a lot less often than you write functions which might raise, so hopefully this isn't a problem.(If it *is* a problem, you can instead add code to `WorkerThread` that gets the singleton app, asks it for its main window, and uses that, and then monkeypatch `threading.Thread = WorkerThread`.)

Comment: Just found an issue that it didn't catch an exception which was in a thread?